# Which song beat is it in Justin Bieber song lonely?

Tags: vocal-styles

Justin Bieber released his new song Lonely which I feel is a beat of some other song which I have listened. But I can’t remember which one.

Listen the song after 40 seconds to 55 seconds. The way he raises his tone in the lyrics and the background music. I feel like I have heard someone singing this.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be anything particularly striking about the pre-chorus section (between 40-55 seconds), so if that's in fact the section you mean, you might have to detail more about what stands out to you about it.

If you're talking about the chorus, that vocal technique is called a "yodel," where the singer switches rapidly in and out of the falsetto voice, creating an audible break between the two voicings. Yodeling is stereotypically associated with the folk music of the Alps, as depicted in the song "The Lonely Goatherd" from *The Sound of Music*. However it's occasionally used in pop music, as in the song *5 O'Clock World*. It's often considered humorous, so it's notable that it's used here to depict serious emotions.